# How do I use @ConfigItem in Quarkus Extension

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-extension

```
@ConfigGroup
public static class Properties {

 @ConfigItem  
 public List<Server> servers = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

When I build projects

Errors:

Runtime java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SRCFG00013: No Converter registered for class io.quarkiverse.xx.xx.cfg.xxx$Server

but build succeeds when I don't use the list

If you know the solution or the related documents, please let me know, thank you

Comment: Is `Server` a `@ConfigGroup`?

Comment: yes，I add @ConfigGroup in Server

Comment: I propose having a look at https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/ebee0a4b66d1b4dba9c51165e78d22fbf3b90d3e/integration-tests/smallrye-config/src/main/java/io/quarkus/it/smallrye/config/Server.java#L131 which contains a bunch of examples of how to use the configuration